# Can the SSD from a 2013 Macbook Air work with an adapter in a PC?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

I happen to have a spare SSD from a 2013 MBA and I'm wondering if anyone knows of an adapter card to use it in a PC? There are boards like this (http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/SSD/PCIe/OWC/Mercury_Accelsior/RAID) or this (http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820249042) that superficially look like they're using the same type of slim SSD card. But on closer inspection, the connector is different.

Answer (score 1):

Try to call or write OWC, I know thier SSD for macbook airs works good so I think thier adaptor work fine aswell. But you have a 2013 and they only sell SSD for pre-2012 Airs, so maybe there is a change in the newest SSD that they does not support yet.

My advice, contact OWC before ordering any.